# How to change class name alternatively in angular

Tags: angular

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
   <li [className]="titleActive ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'">
      <a class="nav-link active wow fadeIn" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home-1" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">HOT JOBS</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link wow fadeIn" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile-1" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">ALL JOBS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Ts file**
titleActive: any = 'true';

**some condition** 
 this.titleActive= 'false';

Comment: Please re-order ur code or else we can't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Angular Version? Or Please provide a Stackblitz Code where I/we can test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to using `[ngClass]`

```
 <li [ngClass]="titleActive == 'true' ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'">
    <!-- content -->
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [*ngClass*](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass),

```
<li [ngClass]="titleActive ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'">
```

Comment: he is using titleActive as string so you might need to compare it with 'true'

Comment: actually it's not a string, it will be evaluated like variable...